# Fabricjs loadFromJSON performance

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have one canvas which can load different pages, how exactly this works on javascript? I have lets say `object` which contain this data and after i change page i am doing something like `delete object;` which i believe free ram so my app can use this again. First 5 pages canvas is smooth and nice but after those with  `loadFromJSON` canvas get really heavy, freezing from time to time. On mac with safari webpage get more then 600mb RAM, which is not happening on chrome for example but work on canvas feel same laggy on both browsers. If there any way to refresh canvas or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to optimise canvas performance you can try to initiate it with         `renderOnAddRemove: true` option:

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasId', {
  renderOnAddRemove: true
});
```

and then call `canvas.renderAll()` after all needed changes are done.

Comment: You can try, as I said. this property disables redrawing the whole canvas after each object is added/removed, so that may save resources on that step.